# Emulating a public Wifi hotspot

Tags: android, windows, wifi

I have already read https://superuser.com/questions/683997/windows-7-8-access-point-no-authentication-encryption and https://superuser.com/questions/593336/how-to-create-an-open-unencrypted-adhoc-wifi-network-in-windows8

I want to create a public Wifi network without any encryption or authentication in order to emulate a public hotspot for Android development purposes. I'm looking for the cheapest way

While Windows provides ways to host an Infrastructure network, it seems to be impossible to create a public network. I know I can buy a cheap router/soapbox*, but I'm looking for a software way. Using Windows. Possibly free

Then I can play with my own captive portal emulation using Apache and a few DNS tricks.

*Wifi-3G modem

Comment: You can create a WLAN hotspot with any android device. What's the problem?

Comment: Uhm.... you are actually correct. I forgot to tell that my Android device must act as client, programmatically connecting to an open network. So well, if I can connect my device under test to another device's hotspot I can test the connection part, but I could be unable to test a captive portal.

Comment: By the way, most "soapboxes" embed a captive portal when you remove the SIM from them, so that is still the best solution